# Grouping notebooks in tkinter using python 3.x

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using tkinter for creating a simple GUI using python 3.x I want to group certain tabs created using `ttk.Notebook` as I have many tabs and the screen size becomes huge and un organised. Is there any way to group the data created using `ttk notebook`

Code till now:

```
gui_optimizer.configure(background="#a1dbcd")

tab = ttk.Notebook(gui_optimizer)

main_options = tkinter.Frame(tab, bg="#a1dbcd") # Main options
file_customizations = tkinter.Frame(tab, bg="#a1dbcd") # File related options
other_options_1 = tkinter.Frame(tab, bg="#a1dbcd") # Most used GUI pages
other_options_2 = tkinter.Frame(tab, bg="#a1dbcd") 
other_options_3 = tkinter.Frame(tab, bg="#a1dbcd")

tab.add(main_options, text='Main options')
tab.add(file_customizations, text='File customizations')
tab.add(other_options_1, text="Aux options 1")
tab.add(other_options_2, text="Aux options 2")
tab.add(other_options_3, text="Aux options 3")
```

I would like to group the `Aux options` into one tab and when I click it it could show the grouped options. Any idea would be really helpful....

Comment: Are you wanting a notebook inside a notebook?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes is it possible?

Comment: Of course. There's no reason it can't be done. You should try it.